# overfull \hbox ..with figures (like to do If scale>width, use max width)

Tags: graphics, conditionals, scaling

Well, I'm having a problem with `figure`.

I'm using figures like this:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{\importacaodedados importacaodearquivos.png} 
\caption{Importação de Arquivos.}
\label{fig:importacaodearquivos}
\end{figure}
```

And I'd like to know if there is a way to IF the scale=1 exceeds the text width, use `[max width = \textwidth]`

It would be really better if there is a way to put it in the style file.
so I won't have to change every figure in the manual. (There are more than 140. Not all of them exceed the text width.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\importacaodedados importacaodearquivos.png}` for those figures that exceed the limit.